# Duplicate rows if cell of specific column have more than one value

Tags: python, pandas

Having a data frame in which two columns may have more than one value separated by ";". How can I create repeated rows per each value found in that column?

Example

```
data = [['chr1', 1,10,'Gene1;Gene10','ID1;ID10'], ['chr2',15,20,'Gene2','ID2'],['chr2',21,40,'Gene3','ID3;ID20']]
LOUEF = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Chromosome_hg38', 'Gene_start_hg38', 'Gene_stop_hg38','Gene_name','geneID'])
LOUEF

  Chromosome_hg38   Gene_start_hg38 Gene_stop_hg38  Gene_name   geneID
0   chr1    1   10  Gene1;Gene10    ID1;ID10
1   chr2    15  20  Gene2   ID2
2   chr2    21  40  Gene3   ID3;ID20
```

Expected results

```
  Chromosome_hg38   Gene_start_hg38 Gene_stop_hg38  Gene_name   geneID
0   chr1    1   10  Gene1   ID1
0   chr1    1   10  Gene10  ID10
1   chr2    15  20  Gene2   ID2
2   chr2    21  40  Gene3   ID3
2   chr2    21  40  Gene3   ID20
```

I guess I need to apply

```
for index,row in LOUEF.iterrows():
```

But then, I don't know how to iterate per row, splitting the value and pasting values in the new columns created. It is very unlikely but probably not always Gene_name and GeneID will have the same number of values as can be seen in the last row

Answer (score 0):

Consider working with a preprocessing function to a row into multiple rows:

```
def expand(row):
    'Return multiple rows from a single row if necessary'
    n = max(val.count(';') + 1 for val in row if isinstance(val, str))
    expanded = [val.split(';')
                if isinstance(val, str) and ';' in val
                else [val] * n
                for val in row]
    return list(zip(*expanded))
```

Example:

```
>>> expand(['chr2', 21, 40, 'Gene3', 'ID3;ID20'])
[('chr2', 21, 40, 'Gene3', 'ID3'), ('chr2', 21, 40, 'Gene3', 'ID20')]
```

Here's how you apply it:

```
newdata = []
for row in data:
    newdata += expand(row)
```

This gives the desired result:

```
>>> newdata
[('chr1', 1, 10, 'ID1', 'Gene1'), ('chr1', 1, 10, 'ID10', 'Gene10'), ('chr2', 15, 20, 'ID2', 'Gene2'), ('chr2', 21, 40, 'ID3', 'Gene3')]
```

Now you can proceed normally:

```
LOUEF = pd.DataFrame(newdata, columns = ['Chromosome_hg38', 'Gene_start_hg38', 'Gene_stop_hg38','Gene_name','geneID'])
```

Comment: I like this approach. However, the data frames have many columns (the one I showed was an example with the column involved) so it is not practical. I like this because I understand what you are doing. Your approach is simpler than the approach of @BENY.

Comment: Can I put a list after the first for? A list that take the column headers?

Comment: @Monkiky I updated this is with a generic *expand()* that gets to the heart of the matter — the fundamental transformation is that multiple rows were encoded in a single row.

Comment: The problem is that I dont have data like that. I started directly with my data frame. So, I am looking for a way to convert the pandas data frame to a list of list. An then, I could try your suggestion.